# Samsung BudsPro2 not visible is the sound device list

Tags: 23.04

I am trying to connect my new BudsPro2 to my Dell laptop running Ubuntu 23.04. The Bluetooth GUI claims that they are connected, but they do not show up in the Output/Input sound device list.
Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?